# Send list to view

Tags: python, json, django

I have code to get list of video from youtube channel and template html with iframe youtube player. I need send array of video classes to view (ListView). How i can do it ?

util class:

```
import requests
import simplejson
from blogapp.video import *
video_channel = "***"
url = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author="+video_channel+"&orderby=updated&v=2&alt=jsonc"


def get_Videos():
    request = requests.get(url)
    data_about = simplejson.load(request.text)
    video_list = []
    for item in data_about['data']['items']:
        same = Video(item['title'],item['id'],item['description'],item['player']['default'])
        video_list.append(same)
    return video_list
```

Video class:
    class Video:
        title = 0
        id = 0
        description = 0
        url = 0

```
    def __init__(self,title,id,description,url):
        self.url=url
        self.title=title
        self.id=id
        self.description=description
```

View:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from blogapp.models import Blog
from blogapp.utils import *
class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = Blog
    context_object_name = 'videos'
    video_array = get_Videos()
    template_name = 'blogapp/video_list.html'
```

Template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Video Posts{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<h2>Video</h2>

    {% if videos %}

        {% for video in videos %}
            <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="720" height="405"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{ video.id }}}"
frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>

        {% endfor %}

{% else %}
    <p>There are no video </p>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this task you should use the [`TemplateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview) instead of `ListView`:

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

class VideoListView(TemplateView):

    template_name = "blogapp/video_list.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(VideoListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['videos'] = get_Videos()
        return context
```

Comment: After, this, i get AttributeError at /blog/ 'unicode' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: Update your question with the staktrace for this error, please.

Comment: I fix it,to add simplejson.loads()